# MongoDB not using wildcard nested array index

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, nosql

I have the following collection:

```
{
   _id: 12345,
   quizzes: [
     { 
        _id: 111111,
        questions: []
     }
   ]
},
{
   _id: 78910,
   quizzes: [
     { 
        _id: 22222
     }
   ]
}
```

I want to select the documents of a certain quiz from the `quizzes` that do not have the `questions` array and want to make sure that it uses the appropriate `questions` index. So I use the following query:

```
Answer.find({ 'quizzes.0.questions': { $exists: false } }).explain('queryPlanner');
```

Which returns:

```
{
   queryPlanner: {
     plannerVersion: 1,
     namespace: 'iquiz.answers',
     indexFilterSet: false,
     parsedQuery: { 'quizzes.0.questions': [Object] },
     winningPlan: { stage: 'COLLSCAN', filter: [Object], direction: 'forward' },
     rejectedPlans: []
   }
 }
```

The query is not using any index as seen from the output. I have tried the following indexes and none get used:

```
{ quizzes.$**: 1 }
{ quizzes.questions: 1 }
{ quizzes.[$**].questions: 1 }
{ quizzes: 1 }
```

The only 1 that actually gets used:

```
{ quizzes.0.questions: 1 }
```

However this is not really practical as I may target any quiz from the quizzes array not just the first one. Is there a certain syntax for the index in my case or this is a current limitation of mongodb? Thanks!

Comment: Your query is to find answers for a question that does not exist? What does that mean?

Comment: This is just a sample so do not need to explain the full logic behind it. Briefly quizzes with no questions are basically answered ones. So I need to select the players who finished a certain quiz.

Comment: Add a field that starts out as 0 which is set to 1 when questions are cleared, query by that field.

Answer (score -1):

Indexes generally do not help to answer queries in the form of "X does not exist". See also [mongodb indexes covering missing values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63003917/mongodb-indexes-covering-missing-values/63005748#63005748).

To verify whether the index is used, look up some data using a positive condition.

Comment: I just tested and I can confirm that the query is faster without index than with index which is quite strange! However the query still takes around 1.7 seconds on a million records. Is that normal? This is a local dev server. On a highly speced production server, would it get faster? Thanks!

Comment: None of these questions are answerable given the information you provided by a person on the internet.

Comment: Using a positive condition does not help. I tried other fields in the array with conditions like `{ $gt` but still no index gets used.

Comment: Add a positive query you tried and the index you used with it to the question.

Comment: I created a question with a positive condition on another field which has your own suggestion of `0` or `1`  for finished quizzes: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/274020/mongodb-not-using-wildcard-nested-array-index